# Are all differential equation systems deterministic? Are there any that aren't?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

So I was looking into different kinds of models used to model the covid-19 pandemic, and looked at both stochastic and deterministic models. However, I was also looking at different kinds of differential equations and came across delay DE's and functional DE's. And I also read some stuff about stochastic differential equations.

Dumb question I guess, but are all systems with these equations deterministic? I'm guessing SDE's *might* produce stochastic systems, but the other two I mentioned should be deterministic, right? Especially if, say, I wanted to model the pandemic by using a DDE, that would be a deterministic model, right? I'm really sorry if this is stupid, I feel like I don't understand well enough what would make a deterministic model and what wouldn't, and I'm really not sure where else to ask. Would appreciate any answers or comments at all. Thank you!

Comment: The passage from DDE to SDE introduces the noisy fluctuations into the dynamical system.

Comment: DEs have deterministic solutions. Perhaps a given DE may have multiple solutions for given initial conditions, but that is not the same thing as non-deterministic. You might want to look into the concept of *master equations* whereby one constructs DEs for quantities such as (using your example of pandemic) $P_n(t)$, the "probability that at time $t$ there are $n$ infected people"

Comment: @Wuestenfux Ohh that's interesting. So these two are related? I thought they were both completely separate things lol. Does the noise affect the deterministic-ness? (Sorry for the bad language skills lmao I didn't know how else to put it, hoping my question makes sense.)

Comment: @Sal Ahhh I see. I'll look into master equations, thank you for the suggestion! Also, so what I get from your comment is that all DE systems *are* deterministic and have deterministic solutions? Also, since, with your example, master equations can be made for probability, would that system be probabilistic/stochastic in nature?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the word _deterministic_ is a meta-mathematical term used to describe everything which isn't _stochastic_ - that should answer the question, right?

Comment: @Applesauce44 Yes that is right about DEs. About master equations: the solutions for say $P_n(t)$ are of course deterministic. They model an underlying stochastic process, hence the quantities solved for are *probabilities*

Comment: @Sal Ohhh okay okay I see, that's interesting, thank you!

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz the problem was that I couldn't find the line between deterministic and stochastic when underlying probabilities came into play. So if I'm working on a system that involves SDE's, or uses probabilities, **that** was where I was getting confused about whether it's stochastic or deterministic. BUT I think I've understood well enough now hopefully lol.